# repair ubuntu server 8.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu-8.04

I just replace the motherboard of my server pc that has been damaged. After replacing the motherboard, 8:04 ubuntu server preinstalled can not boot. How the best way to fix it without deleting the data on the hard drive?

Comment: Re-install with a not-5-years-old distro and then restore from backup.

Comment: What if the data is not backed up? Is there a way to fix without having to delete the data? The data is located in / var / www, / var / liib / mysql

Comment: FYI, 8.04 has been unsupported since April 2013. It's not surprising that it doesn't work with newer hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the old hard drive.
2. Purchase and install a new hard drive.
3. Install a new OS on the new hard drive.
4. Connect the old hard drive to the machine, mount it, and attempt to restore data from it.

If #4 doesn't work, be prepared to fork over a good amount of money to a professional data recovery service.